# Critical section controller accessed by 10 threads at same time

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have single thread group A with 100 users that run the following logic:

```
*REQUEST1 
*REQUEST2
*CRITICAL_SECTION_CONTROLLER 
   -REQUEST3
*TIMER TO WAIT ALL THREADS FINISH
*REQUEST4
```

I would like to run the REQUEST3 by groups, only for 10 users at same time. (now only one user can at time by the section controller)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong configuration element, go for [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer), add it as a child of the request 3 and set "Number of simulated users to group by" to `10`

[image]

Also be aware that if you put a Timer at the same level as all requests [it is executed **before each request** in its scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers), each JMeter thread processes Samplers and stuff individually, if you want to run Request 4 with all 100 users - add the same Synchronizing Timer as its child and set "Number of simulated users to group by" to `100`

More information: [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)